# Problemas con CORS de dos dominios diferentes

Tags: ajax, axios, cors

Hola tengo varios dominios.

> https://api.com
>   y
>   https://front.com

El dominio uno es una api y el dominio 2 es un servidor de frontend

Cuando hago peticiones desde postman al dominio de la api esta se comporta normalmente. Pero cuando hago peticiones desde el dominio del front me salen los problemas de los cors.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://acl.rxmxit.com/api/oauth/token' 
from origin 'https://fenix.rxmxit.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Request header field access-control-allow-origin 
is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

La peticion la estoy haciendo mediante axios.

```js
var data = {};
var headers = {
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", 
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Accept": "application/json"
};

axios.post("https://acl.rxmxit.com/api/oauth/token", data, headers).then(
  res=>{
    console.log(res);
  },
  err=>{
    console.log(err)
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes habilitar los cors en tu app backend para aceptar solicitudes desde tu ip frontend, o utilizar por el momento `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` así: 
`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.com` 
 y eso te soluciona (temporalmente) tu problema de cors

Comment: Tengo laravel de backend instalada la dependencia de CORS Middleware for Laravel pero no funciona. Igual hice un middleware personalizado para que acepte los cors de  Access-Control-Allow-Orign pero no funciona no se si el problema si este efectivamente del lado del backend o este del lado del fronend